# Rearranging the tiles in a Rubik's cube net

Tags: combinatorics, rubiks-cube

Consider the following image:
[image: Rubik's cube net]

Given that there are 54 tiles in this net--9 of each of the 6 colors--we can say that there are $\frac{54!}{9!^6}$ unique ways to arrange the tiles in this net. Now, consider the 6 3x3 squares, each of which have 9 of the same colored tiles. What is the probability that our rearrangement will contain two same-color tiles that are touching (meaning that they share a side)? We do not need to worry about tiles in one 3x3 face touching adjacent tiles that below to another 3x3 face, but simply tiles touching within their respective faces. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Isn't it $\frac{54!}{9!^6}$

Comment: @AlexK Yes, thank you. Fixed.

Comment: My guess is that an exact answer will be incredibly messy. The number of ways to rearrange a single face without same color neighbors is going to be a messy formula that depends on the number of each color in the face. And then you'll take that mess and combine it with another messy formula for different ways to allocate colors to faces.

Comment: I would treat the faces as though independent.  That's not quite right, because for example you can't have one side with all nine of one colour and another side with all six colours; but the nine is quite rare.

Comment: Brief thoughts: If there are $6$ or more squares of one color on one face, there will always be a touching pair. With $5$, exactly *one* arrangement has no touching pairs; with $4$, there are two such arrangements, one with $4$-fold symmetry. With $0$ or $1$, there will never be a touching pair. So the real difficulty is in unfortunately pretty common cases where there are $2$ or $3$ squares of one color on a face.

Comment: If you were to restate this problem somewhere, I suggest that the six 3x3 faces should be separated from each other in the image, which would also allow you to give a simpler description of the problem, since you'd no longer need to include the second-to-last sentence here. I'd also just drop any reference to Rubik's cube, because while the similarities are obvious, you are allowing arrangements that are impossible on the cube (such as moving the center tiles).

Comment: @AlexK: It's not quite as messy as one might expect; see my answer.

Comment: In a Rubiks'cube, we know by advance a lot of properties : for example, the centers of the 6 squares have 6 distinct colors. If I understand correctly, you reject this property. You don't worry about a Rubik's cube but about 6 squares 3x3, totally random.

Comment: @Lourrran Correct, I find it easier to calculate without concern for that, and then to simply multiply that result by the probability that the resulting position is valid.

Comment: Strange. What is your final objective ?  Multiplying by a probability is correct only in some specific circonstances. And for sure it is not correct here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a little help from our electronic friends, this is actually not as difficult to compute  as it might seem. The computation can be organized using generating functions. As is often the case, they serve here merely as a bookkeeping device, and the computation could be formulated without them – I just find it easier to think of convolutions of counts of complicated configurations as products of generating functions.

Associate the monomial $\prod_kx_k^{n_k}$ with a configuration with $n_k$ tiles of colour $k$ . Then a polynomial that is a linear combination with integer coefficients of such monomials represents counts of different configurations. Let $P(x_1,\ldots,x_6)$ denote the polynomial that represents all admissible configurations of one $3\times3$ square, i.e. it counts the ways in which the square can be coloured such that no two adjacent tiles have the same colour. Then the count of admissible configurations of the entire net of $54$ tiles is the coefficient of $x_1^9\cdots x_6^9$ in $P(x_1,\ldots,x_6)^6$.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/joriki/7379ab82455558d548409a7b1b40608e)’s Java code that performs this computation. By making use of the high symmetry of the problem and dropping terms with exponents above $9$, it never needs to retain more than $227$ terms at a time, so the computation doesn’t take long. The result is that there are $779371552365370814877373251723600$ admissible configurations. Thus the probability that no two adjacent tiles have the same colour is

$$
\frac{9!^6\cdot779371552365370814877373251723600}{54!}=\frac{240814346917986285649911399}{31237598017434328973915592130000}\approx7.71\cdot10^{-6}\;.
$$

To check this for plausibility, note that there are $72$ pairs of adjacent tiles and each has a probability of $\frac{9-1}{54-1}=\frac8{53}$ of being monochromatic. If we pretend that these events are all independent, we can estimate the probability of none of them occurring by $\left(\frac{45}{53}\right)^{72}\approx7.65\cdot10^{-6}$, in good agreement with the computation. That the exact probability is slightly higher is plausible, since one might expect positive correlation among the monochromatic pairs – both because a monochromatic $2\times2$ square produces $4$ monochromatic pairs with a probability of roughly $6^{-3}$ instead of $6^{-4}$, and because lots of other pairs being monochromatic makes the distribution of the remaining colours slightly more unbalanced.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/joriki/c185f14930dd67f66de765bc59e45204)’s Java code that performs a simulation to check the result. In a sample of one billion configurations, it found 7728 without monochromatic pairs, for an estimated probability of $7.73\cdot10^{-6}$, again in good agreement with the computation.

To answer your question, which asks for the complementary probability of at least one pair of adjacent tiles having the same colour: The probability for this is about $0.99999229$.

Comment: Woah! Thank you so much. This really helps. I'll definitely use this in the bigger problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: @BaguetteBoy: You're welcome! One more thing that might come in handy if you're actually going to use this in practice: In this case, the polynomials are so small that I could easily calculate the $6$th power explicitly, especially since they shrink again once you get to the $4$th power and a lot of the resulting exponents are above $9$. But if that hadn't been possible, a nice trick would have been to calculate only up to $P^3$ and then for each term find the matching term that would yield $x_1^9\cdots x_6^9$ in $P^3\cdot P^3=P^6$.

Comment: I must admit that I was a little confused by the polynomials notationally. Can you elaborate on what they mean?

Comment: @BaguetteBoy: If you're new to generating functions, a book I can recomment is [generatingfunctionology](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html). You can also find lots of good answers here on math.SE that use generating functions (there's a tag [tag:generating-functions]). For example, the polynomial $Q=3x_1^4x_2^5+2x_1^3x_2^3x_3^3$ counts three configurations with $4$ tiles of colour $1$ and $5$ tiles of colour $2$ and two configurations with $3$ tiles of colours $1$, $2$ and $3$ each. Multiplying polynomials corresponds to combining the corresponding configurations.

Comment: @BaguetteBoy: For instance, if you square the above polynomial, you get $Q^2=9x_1^8x_2^{10}+12x_1^7x_2^8x_3^3+4x_1^6x_2^6x_3^6$, which counts the configurations you get by combining any pair of configurations counted by $Q$. (I just noticed that I wrote "squares" once in the answer where I meant "tiles" – I hope that didn't confuse you – I'm fixing it...)